# app launched through xcode becomes slow after some time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am developing an iOS app where a user can write and read feedbacks of restaurants and can even ask questions from other users directly.

When i launch the app through Xcode, the app runs fine. But on continuous usage for about an hour or two, the app goes super slow. At that time, even keyboard takes about 10 seconds to appear. If i quit the app and relaunch it (either via Xcode or simply reopening it from phone), the speed becomes normal.

I am using a Tab Bar Controller which is further linked to various Navigation Controllers.

From what i think is that there is some memory management issue. I don't have much idea about Instruments but i tried Allocations, Leaks profile but could not find anything.

I googled and found that many people had written to turn on zombies and check for leaks and i have tried that but could not find an answer.

I can post my code but don't know which part could have a problem. So, don't know which part to post.

Any help, links or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the app using Instruments?

Comment: Try running the allocations instrument again and watch for spikes in new memory being allocated as you do certain things within your app. If the memory just keeps growing then that should hone you in on where your problem is. Are you able to run it on a device to see if the same issue occurs?

Comment: i am testing the app on a device only and not on a simulator. when i use allocations instrument, there are no spikes but the memory keeps on increasing with time.

Comment: Are you using wkWebView as a framework for your app?